# Is there a work around for failure to honor import settings in neo4j.conf within the community edition?

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-apoc

This bug has been previously reported but I need a work around to complete a task.  There are some indications that this same bug does not exist in the zip version of the install.  If that's correct where can I get a copy?

Comment: I believe you should update your question and add the steps to reproduce the bug.

Comment: There are indeed some issues with the CE (exe-install) honoring neo4j.conf settings, more specifically on Windows 7. However, you should really specify which issue you are encountering.

Answer (score 1):

To download the zip version, go [here](https://neo4j.com/download/other-releases/) and scroll down to Neo4j Releases.

There should be a workaround on the APOC documentation (at least for OS X) in the download latest release section, as it specified two places to copy the jar.